Airflow - DockerSwarm Operator - Problem containers in workers
This is my setup:
Server A (Airflow 2.10.2)
Server B (Docker 27.4.1) ,Leader of the SWARM
Server C (Docker 27.4.1) , worker of the SWARM.
This is a section of the DAG:
from airflow.contrib.operators.docker_swarm_operator import DockerSwarmOperator

with DAG(DAG_NAME, default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS, schedule_interval='0 4 * * *' , catchup=False, is_paused_upon_creation=False) as dag:

    hop = DockerSwarmOperator(
        task_id='Job_exec_HOP',
        image='apache/hop',
        api_version='auto',
        enable_logging=False,
        auto_remove=False,
        environment= {
            'HOP_RUN_PARAMETERS': 'INPUT_DIR=',
            'HOP_LOG_LEVEL': 'Basic',
            'HOP_FILE_PATH': '${PROJECT_HOME}/BIT_DW/J_BIT_DW_01_ARTICULOS.hwf',
            'HOP_PROJECT_FOLDER': '/files/INDUTOP_BI_ETL_DORIS',
            'HOP_PROJECT_NAME': 'INDUTOP_BI_ETL_DORIS',
            'HOP_SHARED_JDBC_FOLDERS': '/files/JDBC_FOLDER',
            'HOP_RUN_CONFIG': 'local'
        },
        docker_url="tcp://SERVERB:2375",
        network_mode="bridge",
        mounts=[Mount(source='/mnt/hop_bi_etl', target='/files', type='bind')],
        force_pull=False
        )

When the Leader (Server A) created the service/container, it runs OK , and do the callback to airflow finishing succesfully the DAG.
BUT, when the Leader, assigns the service/container to the Worker (Sever C), it runs OK and finishes OK (Exit Code (0),  but on Airflow, the task is set as Failed, as it tries to get status of the container from Server B(Master) no matter that was executed by the worker (ServerC).
FYI:  Ingress network is OK, and both servers B and C are peers.
I appreciate any help on this. Thanks. Daniel
ServerA
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=hop_j01_bit_dw_articulos/run_id=manual__2024-12-23T15:50:24.949373+00:00/task_id=Job_exec_HOP/attempt=1.log
[2024-12-23, 12:50:26 -03] {local_task_job_runner.py:123} ▶ Pre task execution logs
[2024-12-23, 12:50:26 -03] {docker_swarm.py:168} INFO - Starting docker service from image apache/hop
[2024-12-23, 12:50:26 -03] {docker_swarm.py:194} INFO - Service started: {'ID': 'xbq7wh97vop97gqhddddl7gi7', 'Warnings': None}
[2024-12-23, 12:54:28 -03] {docker_swarm.py:205} INFO - Service status before exiting: complete
[2024-12-23, 12:54:28 -03] {taskinstance.py:3310} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 275, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1024, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://ServerB:2375/v1.47/containers/7df77dcdc8cd6040bb0ff1cf163165c15a7594b0ddd104586889a9767ab0521c/json
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 767, in _execute_task
    result = _execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 733, in _execute_callable
    return ExecutionCallableRunner(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/operator_helpers.py", line 252, in run
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 406, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker_swarm.py", line 165, in execute
    return self._run_service()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker_swarm.py", line 212, in _run_service
    container = self.cli.inspect_container(container_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 793, in inspect_container
    return self._result(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 281, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 277, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e) from e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 39, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation) from e
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for http://ServerB:2375/v1.47/containers/7df77dcdc8cd6040bb0ff1cf163165c15a7594b0ddd104586889a9767ab0521c/json: Not Found ("No such container: 7df77dcdc8cd6040bb0ff1cf163165c15a7594b0ddd104586889a9767ab0521c")
[2024-12-23, 12:54:28 -03] {taskinstance.py:1225} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=hop_j01_bit_dw_articulos, task_id=Job_exec_HOP, run_id=manual__2024-12-23T15:50:24.949373+00:00, execution_date=20241223T155024, start_date=20241223T155026, end_date=20241223T155428
[2024-12-23, 12:54:28 -03] {logging_mixin.py:190} WARNING - /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:155 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
[2024-12-23, 12:54:28 -03] {email.py:272} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2024-12-23, 12:54:30 -03] {email.py:283} INFO - Sent an alert email to ['bitecnologia@indutop.uy']
[2024-12-23, 12:54:31 -03] {taskinstance.py:340} ▶ Post task execution logs

